# How to show a contextMenu via code in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I use a context menu on a text, which is correctly displayed by long tapping on the text.
However, I would like to display this menu also by code. Is that possible?

The following sample code should clarify this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Tap and hold…")
                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded({ _ in
                    // Show context menu some how
                    print("Double tapped.")
                }))
        }
        .contextMenu {
            Button("Option 1", action: {})
            Button("Option 2", action: {})
            Button("Option 3", action: {})
        }
    }
}
```